# mobx store not accessable inside lifecycle methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a react component which i am injecting a mobx store. when I try to access an observable from my store inside a lifecycle method (componentWillMount or componentDidMOunt) the value is empty. however when I access it inside the render method it is available. Is there something I am missing? I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: My understanding: mobx will observe for changes of observables accessed within render method and run render if the value changes. Though the value of observable is available in lifecycle methods, it does not watch for changes in those observables, so the re-render will not happen on value change.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. I guess i'm setting a new value up the tree a bit and my child component has already rendered before my value is being set. I'll explore this a bit more.

Comment: do you use the mobx-react bindings? see https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react

Comment: i sure do. I think that vijayst uncovered part of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#observercomponentclass) clearly states that `observer` from `mobx-react` tracks observables only in render method of wrapped component.

> Function (and decorator) that converts a React component definition,
>   React component class or stand-alone render function into a reactive
>   component, which tracks which observables are used by render and
>   automatically re-renders the component when one of these values
>   changes.

If you take a look at [`observer` sources](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/src/observer.js#L201) you can confirm that it only tracks render method

Answer (score 0):

Hi by my experience with Mobx state management you should not access the

observalbe variables from React Component. 
Even when you inject the Redux Store into React Component. (Decorate or wrap).

The computed variables are designed to provide updated observable variables to React Component.

You can access Mobx actions and computed but not the observable. They are used only inside Mobx class.